# Easy MS Excel - MIN column with IF condition checking another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm analyzing some personal expenditures for somebody on Excel.
I have a column for calendar dates and a column for expenditures on that date. 
Of course, there are days when there are no expenditures to record so Excel shows something like `$  -`.

My Question is:

How can I have a column showing the lowest daily expenditure to-date, not considering the days in which expenditures totaled $0.00?

My current function is this: `=IF(MIN($C$6:C6)>0,MIN($C$6:C6),99000)` with 99000 being a randomly chosen number.

What function can I use, for example, so that H6 displays $4.49 and so H23:H26 display $2.11 and so on:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this, entered as an Array Formula

```
=MIN(IF($C$6:C7=0,"",$C$6:C7))
```

Comment: Array formula is entered using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Not needed In 2021 and later (365 included)