# getting Max/Min value in range based on a cell's condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-statements

Greetings to all Excel gurus..

I've got the dataset shown in the image attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma5uB.png)..
I'd like to show the MIN and MAX value of "Price/Oz" based on the condition if the "Doc No" starts with PF.
Any help will be highly appreaciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy MS Excel - MIN column with IF condition checking another column](https://superuser.com/questions/563622/easy-ms-excel-min-column-with-if-condition-checking-another-column)

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't.. :-( 
However, thanks anyway  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula solution for Excel 2010 and above versions.

In `I2` formula copied right to `J2` and all copied down :

```
=AGGREGATE(15-(COLUMN(A1)=2),6,$F$2:$F$7/(LEFT($B$2:$B$7,2)=$H2),1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the solution.. Old school but, works perfectly for aging PCs..

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Formula in cell I2:

```
=MIN(FILTER(Table1[PRICE/OZ],LEFT(Table1[DOC NO],2)=$H2))
```

Formula in cell J2:

```
=MAX(FILTER(Table1[PRICE/OZ],LEFT(Table1[DOC NO],2)=$H2))
```

Use `FILTER` to filter the price column where the first two characters of the DOC NO are equal to the prefix in column H. Then take either the MIN or the MAX of the resulting array.

If you are using an old version of Excel and do not have access to the `FILTER` function, add a column for the DOC TYPE, whose formula is `=LEFT([@[DOC NO]],2)`, then:

MIN:

```
=MINIFS(Table1[PRICE/OZ],Table1[DOC TYPE],$I8)
```

MAX:

```
=MAXIFS(Table1[PRICE/OZ],Table1[DOC TYPE],$I8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @FlexYourData  your solution is the cleanest,  the most advanced and most fathomable solution.. I tried on my friend's laptop who has Excel 365 version and it worked perfectly.. but, unfortunately the PC where I work and I need to do this, has Excel 2016 installed. So, I had to revert to the solution provided by "bosco_yip" down there..

Comment: I must not mess with the structure of the table like adding new columns and so.. because, this file is being read and copied by an external service that imports certain columns and rows referred to according to columns' index numbers.. and modifying that service is out of my reach.